# Convert a String with dots to Date in Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, csv, type-conversion

I'm using pandas and i imported a csv file with a column "Date", the problem is that pandas think it's a string because it's formatted like "21.03.2022" (dd/mm/yy) and because of the dots i can't use pandas.to_datetime(). The errors are:

1. TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
2. TypeError: time data '21.03.2022' does not match format '%d:%m:%Y' (match)

I tried using the pandas.replace() but it doesn't work with internal values.
I'm having the same problem when i try to convert string like "3.140,80" to number for the same reason.

And could someone include how to do the same but with R.
I'm sorry if the question is too noob-livel. Thanks already :)

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) is very good as determining automatically the formats. You can make it explicit while remaining flexible with  `dayfirst=True`:

```
s = pd.Series(['21.03.2022'])
s2 = pd.to_datetime(s, dayfirst=True)
```

or fully explicit:

```
s2 = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

output:

```
0   2022-03-21
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much i thought format was refering to the output, anyways can you help me also with the numeric problem: i can't use pandas.to_numeric() because the strings of numbers are like this "3.140,98" they have dots for the thousands.

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df['col'].replace({'\.': '', ',': '.'}, regex=True))`